# How to do localization with user-configurable nouns in the phrases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

I'm using I18n in a Ruby on Rails project (but the question applies more generally). The application in question allows companies/organisations/hospitals/municipalities/... to offer projects/internships/assignments/experiments/... for students to do/solve as part of their study programme. To this end, the application allows users to configure different parts of the site with custom words for certain terms to make it less confusing for the offerer.

For example, in parts of the site a project would be referred to as "internship", in others it would be "experiment" and in others it would be just "project". To deal with this in localization, there are a few variables made available for the "current_project_word" and also its plural form. The word also can only be chosen from a fixed set to make sure that we know the different translations of each word in all supported languages.

In the locales this looks like:

```yaml
en:
  ...:
    offer_project: Click the "offer %{projects_word}" button to offer a %{project_word}
```

This will nicely show some users the option to offer internships, while others are presented with the option to offer experiments, projects, assignments, etc, depending on the context in the application.

The problem is that there are some words in sentences that are affected by the specific word used. For example its "a project" but "an experiment". In other languages this problem can be more severe, e.g. in German every word has 1 of 3 genders which is relevant for which article to use (and a complex case system making matters even more complex). And similarly, in Dutch and German, demonstrative pronouns and references to terms in other places in the sentence vary in a similar way depending on the word (so it's not always a preceding or following word that is affected either).

Of course, I try to rephrase sentences such that the rest of the sentence is fixed regardless of the actual word used, but this is not possible for every sentence in every language and sometimes yields quite awkward sentences (more so in German and Dutch than in English).

My question is, is there a better way in which I can have the other words in the sentence vary depending on the actual word used. Or is there perhaps a general approach in localization to solve this problem or make this less of an issue? Or perhaps is there a way to run code in I18n strings such that I can do things like `offer_project: Offer %{determine_article(project_word)} %{project_word}` and have some methods implement the rules for these different words / lookup the different forms for these words without needing to define a million variables?

Comment: Presumably the word selections are very slow changing... if that's the case can you use a translation service API to capture the correctly-gendered translation at the time that the selections are made?

Comment: I forgot to mention... of course you would cache the translation in the database

Comment: @LesNightingill Interesting idea, so you suggest to "fix up" the sentence or rather to do the translations from a language with simpler rules? Indeed, it would be feasible as we can cache these values pretty reliably. However I don't know about the reliability/accuracy of these translation service APIs, do you have any experience there?

Comment: Well the translation services are quite good, but not foolproof. So I would suggest including the ability to review and edit the translation. Also, we now have ChatGPT, so this might be an alternative translation capability to explore... I have no experience with this, but I imagine that it should capture the context of the sentence better. But perhaps the translation services, too, are better now, with our AI innovations, than they were a couple of years ago when I was working on an internationalized app.

Comment: Yes... I'm suggesting that you translate the entire sentence and cache the translations. Perhaps you mention this in your question, but if not, remember that verbs can change in some languages depending on the gender of the subject. As I thought about this interesting question today, I believe that the least complex approach is to translate the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, there's no built in feature for things like articles (only for pluralization, and I'm not sure how good that is outside of English). Also no, the interpolation in i18n is simple string substitution, it doesn't run any code in the placeholder.

Seeing as these words are all known beforehand, I would just have two different locale entries, one for the bare word and one for the article. And then my strings would become:

```yaml
  offer_project: Click the "offer %{projects_word}" button to offer %{article} %{project_word}
  articles:
    default: a
    experiment: an
```

...and I'd nest the lookups:

```rb
I18n.t "offer_project", projects_word: pw.pluralize, project_word: pw, article: I18n.t(pw, scope: :articles, default: :default)
```

Comment: Hadn't thought about nesting the lookups, that's a pretty good idea to avoid an overflow of variables floating around!